# sql combine rows with same date

Tags: sql, ddl, sql-server-2017, dml

I want to combine rows when they have same date and Item# while aggregating received QTY and Outstanding QTY. Also, PO# should be combined with “, “.

Please refer to the image or table below.
Thank you in advance!!

This is my SQL Query...

```
SELECT * 
from [mason01].[dbo].[po_east] as t1
inner join (select distinct [Date],[ITEMNO],[PONUMBER],[LOCATION],[Received],[Outstanding]
  FROM [mason01].[dbo].[po_east] group by [Date], [ITEMNO],[PONUMBER],[LOCATION],[Received],[Outstanding]) as t2
  on t1.Date=t2.Date and t1.ITEMNO=t2.ITEMNO
```

Date ITEMNO PONUMBER LOCATION Received Outstanding

> 4/22/2018 MA1005 SON18497 SF 50 50
>   4/22/2018 MA1005 SON18562 SF 300 0

Date ITEMNO PONUMBER LOCATION Received Outstanding

> 4/22/2018 MA1005 SON18497, SON18562 SF 350 50

**Refer this image:**

[image: Refer to this image]

Comment: Good. So, what is the question? Is it not working? If so, how? What do you get? Wrong data? Any errors?

Comment: Please don't post images. Copy and paste as text instead.

Comment: Hi GolezTrol, It just add t2 to next t1. So, there are 10(5+5) columns with duplicated values.

Comment: Thank you for revising format!! i m pretty new to stackoverflow. Thank you again!

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? Combined with SELECT DISTINCT!?!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: When posting a database-related question, be sure to tag with the specific database vendor (I'm guessing SQL-Server here) and also with a specific version tag (i.e. Sql-Server-2016).

Comment: Thank you Zohar Peled! I revised tags.
I will take a look at your links! Thank you :)

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Please read & act on [mcve]. PS Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn to use @ to notify one non-poster non-sole commenter of a comment it is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using stuff() function

```
SELECT
      [Date],[ITEMNO],[LOCATION],sum([Received]) as [Received] ,sum([Outstanding]) as [Outstanding]
      ,ponum = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + b.[PONUMBER]
          FROM [mason01].[dbo].[po_east] b
          WHERE a.[Date] = b.[Date] and a.[ITEMNO]=b.[ITEMNO]
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM [mason01].[dbo].[po_east] a
group by [Date],[ITEMNO],[LOCATION]
```

Comment: ohh,, i didn't know that there was function like that.. i just accepted your answer as the best answer.